# [DICOM][MergeCOM] MC3 E: Total attribute length (4) not a multiple of size

Tags: dicom

I have an older version of mergecom library( V4.4.0 ). And now I received the  latest version(V5.4.0 ). When I tried to integrate the latest MergeCom library I am getting following error on C-ECHO( logged in merge.log ).

```
DICOM;(20936) 06-21 17:59:01.28 MC3 E: Total attribute length (4) not a multiple of size                                                                                            
DICOM;(20936) 06-21 17:59:01.28 MC3 E: for VR (UN): 8, tag '0x0'                                                                                                                    
DICOM;(20936) 06-21 17:59:01.28 MC3(ReadMessageToTag) E: Message received encoded improperly Invalid VR length in stream data .
```

Please find the attached wireshark logs snapshots

**Wireshark**
 [image: **Wireshark**]

**1. ASSOCIATION-RQ**
[image: **ASSOCIATION-RQ**]

**2.ASSOCIATION-RSP**
[image: **ASSOCIATION-RSP**]

**3.ECHO-RQ**
[image: **ECHO-RQ**]

**4.ECHO-RSP**
[image: **ECHO-RSP**]

**5.ABORT**
[image: **ABORT**]

Comment: The issue occurred due to wrong version of merge dlls

Answer (score 0):

The error log from MergeCOM-3 is implying a parsing error when reading the C-ECHO-RSP. The log message is implying MergeCOM-3 did not identify the group 0 element's value representation, and instead interpreted it as UN.

From the appearance of the C-ECHO-RSP in the WireShark capture, it appears to be encoded properly and WireShark was able to decode the C-ECHO-RSP.

Were there any other errors in the logs?  Is your data dictionary being loaded properly, such that the library would know the VR of the group 0 length tag (0000,0000)?